# Checkbox change does not fire jquery event only first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page with this checkbox:

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary btn-xs ">
      <input id="informativa" type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" checked>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the following js code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#informativa").on("change", function(event){
            if(this.checked) {
                alert("Checked");
                return;
            }
            alert("Unchecked");
        });
    
    });
```

The event change is fired just from the second time I check/uncheck the box. I can't make it working from the first click check.

Comment: It's working from first time. Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/ajt0te8g/

Comment: maybe it's a browser thing. Tested in Chrome and FF and worked fine.

Comment: found the error if I remove checked from the html tag works

Comment: to me it works even with checked in the html tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this -

```
$("#informativa").change(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        alert("Checked");
    }else{
        alert("Unchecked");
    }
});
```

It's tested and working for me.